# How can I insert an admob banner into my app?

Tags: react-native, admob

I need to insert an admob banner in the app, I followed a lot of tutorials on internet but any of thoose works. Can someone help me? I'm using an android emulator

Comment: you can use https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob

Comment: plz share the errors you got when you tried to setup admob in your app...

Comment: there aren't errors, the app just don't open

Comment: I will try another time with reat-native-admob

Comment: now It gives me and error:<<  Invariant Violation:requireNativeComponent:"RNGADBannerView" was not found in the UIManager>>

Comment: I solved this error by linking react-native-admob, but now the app doesn't give any error and just crashes. In the code, in the import It tells me "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-admob",but I added react-native-admob and linked It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code I used with react native admob is:

```
import {
    AdMobBanner,
    AdMobInterstitial,
    PublisherBanner,
    AdMobRewarded,
  } from 'react-native-admob'
```

....

```
<View>
    <AdMobBanner
    adSize="fullBanner"
    adUnitID="ca-app-pub-2174326550695558/6129769558"
    onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
    />
</View>
```

but  It gives me and error:<< Invariant Violation:requireNativeComponent:"RNGADBannerView" was not found in the UIManager>>

Comment: By stop using react native and start using c# on unity

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/admob/reference/Banner) for admob, it's works like charm for my app.